# Matching network for two-port with internally matched inputs/outputs

Tags: measurement, impedance-matching, microwave, s-parameters, smith-chart

### Background

I had a lab in school where we were given an [LNA with inputs/outputs matched to 50Ω](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adl8104.pdf), that will be connected to a 50Ω system:

[image: System overview]

The task was to design the input and output matching networks:

[image: System overview with matching networks added]

And here is my first source of confusion – which is the matching networks needed when we already have internal matching in the LNA, and the same system impedance that it is already matched to? My assumption is that we do it to reduce mismatch introduced by interconnect – is that true?

Starting by the input matching network, we were instructed to terminate the LNA with a 50 Ω load to be able to measure S11:

[image: S11 measurement setup]

This is reasonable since the measurement of S11 requires V2+ (a2) = 0. Thereafter, the matching network was designed using a Smith Chart and observing minimization of reflections by continuously measuring S11.

### Question

We design the matching network to reduce mismatch (and henceforth reflection). However, when designing the input matching network, we simply terminate the output side with an ideal matched load, with no consideration to the effect we are working to reduce.

Wouldn't the resulting matching network be better/more effective, if we already had a matching network on the output, properly matching the load? This puts us in a kind of catch 22 situation, where we need good matching on either side to properly design the matching network on the other side.

How is this usually solved in real life? Will the effect of adding the final matching network be greater, than the approximations caused by ignoring the need of a matching network on the other side?